# Writing to adjacent array elements from different threads?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, x86

Are there any modern, common CPUs where it is unsafe to write to adjacent elements of an array concurrently from different threads?  I'm especially interested in x86.  You may assume that the compiler doesn't do anything obviously ridiculous to increase memory granularity, even if it's technically within the standard.

I'm interested in the case of writing arbitrarily large structs, not just native types.

Note:

Please don't mention the performance issues with regard to false sharing.  I'm well aware of these, but they're of no practical importance for my use cases.  I'm also aware of visibility issues with regard to data written from threads other than the reader.  This is addressed in my code.

Clarification:  This issue came up because on some processors (for example, old DEC Alphas) memory could only be addressed at word level.  Therefore, writing to memory in non-word size increments (for example, single bytes) actually involved read-modify-write of the byte to be written **plus some adjacent bytes** under the hood.  To visualize this, think about what's involved in writing to a single bit.  You read the byte or word in, perform a bitwise operation on the whole thing, then write the whole thing back.  Therefore, you can't safely write to adjacent bits concurrently from different threads.

It's also theoretically possible, though utterly silly, for a compiler to implement memory writes this way when the hardware doesn't require it.  x86 can address single bytes, so it's mostly not an issue, but I'm trying to figure out if there's any weird corner case where it is.  More generally, I want to know if writing to adjacent elements of an array from different threads is still a practical issue or mostly just a theoretical one that only applies to obscure/ancient hardware and/or really strange compilers.

Yet another edit:  Here's a good reference that describes the issue I'm talking about:

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0321246780/threads-and-locks/ch17lev1sec6

Comment: Then perhaps I don't understand what you're asking. You want to know if writing a DWORD to, say, address `0x08450380` will affect any memory locations other than `0x08450380` through `0x08450383`? I would be seriously concerned if that were possible.

Comment: @Jim:  It actually is possible at least on a few (old) architectures.  Some architectures can't write at a granularity of a single byte.  I don't know the details of this, but I do know that, on certain DEC alphas, you can't safely write to adjacent bytes from different threads because memory writes can only be in word granularities.  To understand this, think about trying to write to adjacent bits of the same byte from different threads.  You'd have to read in a whole byte, do bit twiddling, then write a whole byte back.

Comment: I dunno, you are chasing a ghost.  Yes, cores like Alpha and Itanium had crappy memory models.  That's why we don't use them anymore.

Comment: not sure what you exactly want to do but writing by different cores to the same cache lines will incur performance penalty. Look up "false sharing". Generally speaking, you don't want different cores (esp. w/ different L1 caches) to modify the same cache line (i.e. "writing to adjacent array elements")

Comment: @bestsss:  Please reread the question.  I had stated that I'm aware of this issue.  To clarify, the writes to adjacent elements will occur infrequently enough that I don't care if they're somewhat inefficient as long as they're correct.  (However, writes to far-apart elements will occur much more frequently and performance matters here, so locking on every write is not a good option.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely, writing a mis-aligned word that straddles the CPU cache line boundary is not atomic.

Comment: Please see my edit:  What does atomicity have to do with word tearing?

Comment: A memory update that takes more than a single bus cycle (tearing) is by definition not atomic.  I don't know if there are CPU architectures that have non-atomic updates on native words that don't involve tearing.  Probably.

Comment: I think maybe there are two definitions of tearing or something.  I thought it meant that writing to adjacent but not overlapping memory addresses concurrently is not necessarily safe.

Comment: Provide good reference links in your question so everybody is talking about the same thing.

Comment: I'd like to but the vast majority of what Google yields on the subject is old forum posts, folklore, etc.  I was actually hoping this question would lead to some good references because, if they're out there, I sure can't find them.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a native sized value (i.e. 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes) is atomic (well, 8 bytes is only atomic on 64-bit machines).  So, no.  Writing a native type will always write as expected.

If you're writing multiple native types (i.e. looping to write an array) then it's possible to have an error if there's a bug in the operating system kernel or an interrupt handler that doesn't preserve the required registers.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the second paragraph ("a bug in the operating system kernel or an interrupt handler that doesn't preserve the required registers")? Thanks.

Comment: @aix: Imagine that your code is using EDI as a destination index. An interrupt comes along between writes and the interrupt handler destroys the value of EDI--doesn't preserve it. Same thing could happen if there was a bug in the OS kernel's thread context switching. Granted, the likelihood of either of those things happening is rather remote. The point being that once you're dealing with more than just your own code, anything can happen.